# DevExpress XAF, Application Model, Combo box Just Show "OId"

Tags: devexpress, xaf

When I add a member to my `BOModel` and write a simple expression like:

```
[Name] +' ' + [Age]
```

But in runtime I see something like this:

```
ROP.Module.BusinessObjects.ROP.Product(4)
```

That field just show me "OId" but not show related value!

**Note:** that fields are simple textbox is OK, but that fields came from relation to other table are missing.

Please guide me how to solve this issue.

Some screen shot :

[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAQXn.png][1]][1]

[![https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5I2Q.png][2]][2]

Answer (score 0):

in your class, add this line :

```
namespace YourApp.Module.BusinessObjects
{

[Default Property ("Field401")] // add this line
[DefaultClassOptions]
```

Field401 is the field you want to display during the runtime.

Comment: First of all tnx for your kind attention, I add that codes but I didn't catch answer, I edit my post and post another screenshot for more details

Comment: Sorry I haven't Enough Reputation and I couldn't upload them here and refer those links:

https://s18.postimg.org/elujv3qgp/image.png
[Add codes on product class]


https://s11.postimg.org/fx1fi291v/j_2.png
[Data Model On My Solution]


https://s16.postimg.org/3nzgbpvid/j_4.png
[My registration class]


https://s22.postimg.org/l7vkk8ptt/j_3.png
[My Wrong OutPut that be showed Oid]


Tnx a lot

Comment: I am sure that my solution is correct, check the structure of your class, there probably is something wrong.. im not sure but try to remove this line :
[DevExpress.Xpo.DisplayName[@"Product"]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [XafDefaultProperty](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#eXpressAppFramework/CustomDocument113525) attribute.

```
namespace Rop.Module.BusinessObjects
{

    [XafDefaultProperty("DescRegistation")]
    [DefaultClassOptions]
    public partial class Product
    {
    ...

    }
}
```

If the property that you want to display in another object's view is not the one you wish to set as default, then you can set it in the Model Editor as shown in the above link.